# Test for a number in bash

Tags: bash, regular-expression, numeric-data, syntax

Is this the correct way to test for a number,  with double `[[]]` enclosing `:digit:` and single quotes surrounding the regex ?

```
if [[ "$var" =~ '^[[:digit:]]+$' ]]; then
```

Comment: 1.234 and -66 are both numbers. Do you want to test for non-negative integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not, as a simple test will show us:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in 1 2 3 a b c; do
  if [[ "$var" =~ '^[[:digit:]]+$' ]]; then
    echo "$var is a number"
  else
    echo "$var is NOT a number"
  fi
done
```

Running the above produces:

```
1 is NOT a number
2 is NOT a number
3 is NOT a number
a is NOT a number
b is NOT a number
c is NOT a number
```

If you have an editor that runs `shellcheck` automatically, or if you paste your code into https://shellcheck.net/, you'll see the following error:

```
Line 4:
        if [[ "$var" =~ '^[[:digit:]]+$' ]]; then
                        ^-- SC2076 (warning): Remove quotes from right-hand side of =~ to match as a regex rather than literally.
```

And that tells us we should instead write:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in 1 2 3 a b c; do
    if [[ "$var" =~ ^[[:digit:]]+$ ]]; then
        echo "$var is a number"
    else
        echo "$var is NOT a number"
    fi
done
```

Which produces:

```
1 is a number
2 is a number
3 is a number
a is NOT a number
b is NOT a number
c is NOT a number
```

This is documented in the [bash man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and matched accordingly... *If any part of the pattern is quoted, the quoted portion is matched literally.  This means every character in the quoted portion matches itself, instead of having any special pattern matching meaning.*

Comment: "44.7 is NOT a number" and "-73 is NOT a number" - your test only considers non-negative integers

Comment: Depends on the version of bash and whether the compat31 option is enabled.

Comment: @roaima It's true, this only checks for integers, which appears to be what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: I want only to test for integers as I want the values to refer to the context number in `grep`.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you mean by number. `0x12`, `inf`, `1.2`, `-12`, `¹²³`, `⑱`, `1e6`, `1,000,000`, `Ⅷ`, `0x123p-5`,  `6,23`, `0b100110` are all numbers by some definitions of *number*, and `08`, `019`, `9999999999999999999999999999999999` are not valid numbers by some others.

To test whether a string is made of one or more ASCII decimal digits, you can use:

Standardly:

```
valid() {
  case $1 in
    ("" | *[!0123456789]*) false;;
    (*) true;;
  esac
}
```

Or in ksh, bash (`bash -O extglob` with older versions) or `zsh -o kshglob`:

```
valid() [[ $1 = +([0123456789]) ]]
```

Or in bash / ksh93 / zsh / yash:

```
valid() [[ $1 =~ ^[0123456789]+$ ]]
```

`valid() [[ $1 =~ '^[0123456789]+$' ]]` would also work in zsh¹ and bash 3.1 or `bash -O compat31`. In `zsh`, if the `rematchpcre` option was enabled, you'd need to change it to `[[ $1 =~ '^[0123456789]\z' ]]` as `$` in PCRE matches at the end of the subject but also before a newline character at the end of the subject so would match on `$'123\n'` for instance. You could also use `[[ $1 =~ '^\d+\z' ]]` then.

In `zsh`:

```
valid() [[ $1 = <-> ]]
```

In any case, avoid `[[:digit:]]` which on some systems matches decimal digits other than the ASCII arabic ones. And except in zsh, and especially in bash, do not use `[0-9]` for input validation as that often match random characters that happen to sort between 0 and 9.

---

<sup>¹ Note however that in zsh, variable values can contain the NUL byte and the standard regexp API (as opposed to PCRE's) doesn't support matching strings with NULs in them. When the `rematchpcre` option is not enabled, `[[ $1 =~ '^[0123456789]+$' ]]` would match on `$'123\0xyz'` for instance.</sup>